# Pyomo constraint and how to calculate parameter from other parameters

Tags: python, parameters, constraints, pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo and I have the following codes and encountered two errors:

1. Related to adding the constraint of "total_TACperyear". It gives me the below error:
   ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint TACperyear_cons
   with index 1: NameError: name 'techs' is not defined
   ERROR: Constructing component 'TACperyear_cons' from data=None failed:
   NameError: name 'techs' is not defined

*return sum(m.amount_installed_techs[techs,suppliers,years] for techs in m.techs for suppliers in m.suppliers)*m.TAC[techs,suppliers] <= m.totalTACperyear[years]*

NameError: name 'techs' is not defined

2. If i skip the above error, i'll get another error when calculating a parameter (m.product_demands) from the other parameters. I don't know if we can do this in Pyomo. The error is:

ERROR: Rule failed for Param 'product_demands' with index ('daerah_A',
'prod_A', 2): TypeError: Cannot create a Set from data that does not
support **contains**.  Expected set-like object supporting
collections.abc.Collection interface, but received 'float'.
ERROR: Constructing component 'product_demands' from data=None failed:
TypeError: Cannot create a Set from data that does not support
**contains**.  Expected set-like object supporting
collections.abc.Collection interface, but received 'float'.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

# define model
m = AbstractModel() 

# define set
m.techs = Set()
m.products = Set()
m.suppliers = Set()
m.demands = Set()
m.years = Set()

# define parameters
m.initial_demand = Param(m.demands,m.products)
m.growth = Param(m.demands,m.products)
m.yields = Param(m.techs,m.products,m.suppliers)
m.emission = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)
m.TAC = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)
m.max_installed = Param(m.techs,m.suppliers)
m.totalTACperyear = Param(m.years)
m.totalCO2peryear = Param(m.years)

# define independent variables
m.installed_techs = Var(m.techs, m.suppliers, m.years, within=Binary)
m.amount_installed_techs = Var(m.techs, m.suppliers, m.years, bounds=(0,None))
m.totalTAC = Var(bounds=(None,None))
m.totalCO2 = Var(bounds=(None,None))

# objective function
def total_TAC(m):
    return sum(m.totalTACperyear[years] for years in m.years)
m.economics = Objective(rule=total_TAC, sense=minimize)

# other functions
def total_CO2(m):
    return m.totalCO2 == sum(m.totalCO2peryear[years] for years in m.years)

m.totalCO2_cons = Constraint(rule=total_CO2)


def total_TACperyear(m,years):
    return sum(m.amount_installed_techs[techs,suppliers,years] for techs in m.techs for suppliers in m.suppliers)*m.TAC[techs,suppliers] <= m.totalTACperyear[years]

m.TACperyear_cons = Constraint(m.years, rule=total_TACperyear)

# calculate a parameter from parameters
def demandsperyear(m,demands, products, years):
    if years==1:
        
        return m.initial_demand[demands,products]
    
    return m.initial_demand[demands,products]*(1 + m.growth[demands,products]*m.years)

m.product_demands = Param(m.demands, m.products,m.years, initialize=demandsperyear)

# parameter
data = {None: {
    'techs' : {None: ['tek_A', 'tek_B', 'tek_C']},
    'products' : {None: ['prod_A', 'prod_B', 'prod_C']},
    'suppliers' : {None: ['daerah_A', 'daerah_B', 'daerah_C']},
    'demands' : {None: ['daerah_A', 'daerah_B', 'daerah_C']},
    'years' : {None: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13, 14, 15,16,17,18,19,20,
                      21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26,27,28,29,30]},
    'initial_demand': {('daerah_A','prod_A'): 10, ('daerah_A','prod_B'): 10, ('daerah_A','prod_C'): 10,
                        ('daerah_B','prod_A'): 20, ('daerah_B','prod_B'): 20, ('daerah_B','prod_C'): 20,
                        ('daerah_C','prod_A'): 12, ('daerah_C','prod_B'): 12, ('daerah_C','prod_C'): 12},
    'growth': {('daerah_A','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_A','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_A','prod_C'): 0.02,
                        ('daerah_B','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_B','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_B','prod_C'): 0.02,
                        ('daerah_C','prod_A'): 0.02, ('daerah_C','prod_B'): 0.02, ('daerah_C','prod_C'): 0.02},
    'max_installed' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 100,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 100,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 100},
    'TAC' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 100,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 100,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 100, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 100, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 100},
    'emission' : {('tek_A','daerah_A'): 20, ('tek_A','daerah_B'): 20, ('tek_A','daerah_C'): 20,
                        ('tek_B','daerah_A'): 20, ('tek_B','daerah_B'): 20, ('tek_B','daerah_C'): 20,
                        ('tek_C','daerah_A'): 20, ('tek_C','daerah_B'): 20, ('tek_C','daerah_C'): 20},
    'yields': {('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_A','prod_A','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_A','prod_B','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_A','prod_C','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_B','prod_A','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_B','prod_B','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_B','prod_C','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_C','prod_A','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_C','prod_B','daerah_C'):8,
                    ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_A'):8, ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_B'):8, ('tek_C','prod_C','daerah_C'):8},
    'totalTACperyear': {1: 10^6, 2: 10^6, 3: 10^6, 4: 10^6, 5: 10^6, 6: 10^6, 7: 10^6, 8: 10^6, 9: 10^6, 10: 10^6,
                         11: 10^6, 12: 10^6, 13: 10^6, 14: 10^6, 15: 10^6, 16: 10^6, 17: 10^6, 18: 10^6, 19: 10^6, 20: 10^6,
                         21: 10^6, 22: 10^6, 23: 10^6, 24: 10^6, 25: 10^6, 26: 10^6, 27: 10^6, 28: 10^6, 29: 10^6, 30: 10^6},
    'totalCO2peryear': {1: 10^6, 2: 10^6, 3: 10^6, 4: 10^6, 5: 10^6, 6: 10^6, 7: 10^6, 8: 10^6, 9: 10^6, 10: 10^6,
                         11: 10^6, 12: 10^6, 13: 10^6, 14: 10^6, 15: 10^6, 16: 10^6, 17: 10^6, 18: 10^6, 19: 10^6, 20: 10^6,
                         21: 10^6, 22: 10^6, 23: 10^6, 24: 10^6, 25: 10^6, 26: 10^6, 27: 10^6, 28: 10^6, 29: 10^6, 30: 10^6}
    }}

instance = m.create_instance(data)
```

any help, please

Zulfan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple syntax issues here.  In Line 42 which is this one, the first one giving you problems:

```
def total_TACperyear(m,years):
    return sum(m.amount_installed_techs[techs,suppliers,years] for techs in m.techs for suppliers in m.suppliers)*m.TAC[techs,suppliers] <= m.totalTACperyear[years]
```

the `techs` and `suppliers` for `m.TAC[...]` are NOT defined.  You need to supply the source for them like you did in the preceding summary statement.  I'm guessing you want to do element-wise multiplication which should get you something like this, but this is just a guess:

```
def total_TACperyear(m, yr):
    return sum(m.amount_installed_techs[tech,supplier, yr] * m.TAC[tech, supplier] for tech in m.techs for supplier in m.suppliers) <= m.totalTACperyear[yr]
```

Also, when you are enumerating through the elements in a set, I find it much more readable to use singular and plural versions of the element name.  Right now you are repeatedly saying "for `techs` in `m.techs`".  I think it is much more readable, and less error prone to use "for `tech` in `m.techs`" as it is then very clear which is the element and which is the set.

You have a similar problem in this line:

```
return m.initial_demand[demands,products]*(1 + m.growth[demands,products]*m.years)
```

I would first fix all the singular/plural names inside of that function.  Then ...  What are you trying to do here.  You are multiplying `m.growth[]` times a set ?  Makes no sense...

Comment: Thanks AirSquid! I did miss that syntax issue.
For the 2nd problem, I want to calculate the parameter m.growth[demand,product] with the value of the set m.years, which are 1 till 30. For example: 
for year = 1, then m.growth[]*1
for year = 2, then m.growth[]*2
and so on.   
Can we or how can we do this?

Comment: OK.  You are passing in `years` to the function already.  (I would just use `year` as mentioned before).  So if you do it this way, just get rid of the `m.` and just leave it as `years`.  Realize, you can also do this easier in basic python to build this parameter *outside* of `pyomo` and just bring it in after done.  If that doesn't make sense, comment back...